# Why time taken to execute code changes with one line?

Tags: python, time, execution

This is my first code:

```
def isAnagram(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    for i in s:
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True
```

This is my second code:

```
def isAnagram(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    for i in set(s):
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True
```

This is my third code:

```
def isAnagram(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    for i in set(s[:]):
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True
```

I don't understand why replacing `s` with `set(s)` in 4th line takes less time to execute and replacing with `set(s[:])` is even more better than the other two statements.

Can anyone help me to know why this happens?

Comment: Converting the string to a set will remove all the duplicates, so you'll iterate fewer times.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why `set(s[:])` is better than `set(s)`. It should be a little worse because it has to make a copy of the list before converting it to a set.

Comment: Depending on how exactly the code is being tested, later runs may be faster because of cache-warming.

Comment: Also, you can reduce your function to `return sorted(s) == sorted(t)` to check for anagrams

Comment: Showing how you tested is important. If you didn't use `timeit` to warm your caches and turn off garbage collection, then the test is probably unreliable. (though that puts us in an odd position here, because `s[:]` creates extra garbage collection work, so in a real-world situation it very much decreases throughput, even if that effect is delayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After performing `%timeit` I found that @Barmar observation is correct. You should perform timeit on these function.
`set(s[:])` is expensive as compared to `set(s)`

For these 4 functions:

```
def isAnagram(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    a = set(s)
    for i in a:
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True

def isAnagram1(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    a = set(s[:])
    for i in a:
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True

def isAnagram2(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    for i in set(s):
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True

def isAnagram3(s,t):
    if len(s)!=len(t):
        return False
    for i in set(s[:]):
        if s.count(i)!=t.count(i):
            return False
    return True

a = "abcde"
b = "edabc"
%timeit isAnagram(a, b)
%timeit isAnagram1(a,b)
%timeit isAnagram2(a,b)
%timeit isAnagram3(a,b)
```

I got following output:

```
958 ns ± 5.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.01 µs ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
967 ns ± 9.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
987 ns ± 2.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Also fastest method to check anagram will be XOR operator.

```
def isAnagramXOR(s, t):
    res = 0
    for i,j in zip(s, t):
        res ^= ord(i) ^ ord(j)
    return not bool(res)
```

Performance: `667 ns ± 2.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`